# Django, wsgi, apache, MySQL setup/configs in windows

Tags: python, django, windows, apache

Python/Django newbie requesting help in configuring Django, wsgi, MySQL, and apache in windows. Apologies if this has been answered before(tried searching, and it was for linux set up)

I am using Django 1.7, Python 3.4.1, Apache 2.2 for my setup.

I followed the Django documentation and was able to get the Polls application working with MySQL configured. I tried to port the application to use apache instead of the Python web server and having issues.

I get the following error in the Apache error.log file

```
 [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.7.1-py3.4.egg\\django\\db\\backends\\mysql\\base.py", line 17, in <module>\r
 [client 127.0.0.1]     raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)\r
 [error] [client 127.0.0.1] django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'\r
```

My set up files are as below:

### wsgi.py(tried modifying the default file)

```
import django
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
def get_wsgi_application():
    """
    The public interface to Django's WSGI support. Should return a WSGI
    callable.
    Allows us to avoid making django.core.handlers.WSGIHandler public API, in
    case the internal WSGI implementation changes or moves in the future.
    """
    # For PyMySQL
    try:
        import pymysql
        pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
    except ImportError:
        pass
    django.setup()
    return WSGIHandler()

def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = 'Hello World!111'

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]


import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

### httpd.conf

```
WSGIScriptAlias /mysite C:/Python34/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath C:/Python34/mysite

<Directory C:/Python34/mysite/mysite>
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I am sure I am missing something simple. Thanks again.

---

### Reply:

Thanks for the reply. The original wsgi file was as below:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

But I wanted to use MySQL DB, how do I configure that?

When I was using the default python webserver, I used the following piece in manage.py

```
try:
    import pymysql
    pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Is there any other file that I can use to make my app use MySQL?

Thanks.

Comment: What is that WSGI file? You're supposed to just use the one that is created inside your project directory, which is only a few lines long and should not need much modification: you definitely don't need those functions.

Comment: I have updated my original question to include my comments.

Comment: Firstly, you don't need to use pymsql in order to use MySQL: the normal MYSQLdb library works fine and doesn't need this initialisation step. Secondly, why can you not put those two lines straight into the normal WSGI file?

Comment: Thanks again. I was told to use pymsql for MySQL DB. I am fine with using it too unless you think MYSQLdb is better.

I added the 2 lines outside the functions and it seemed to work. Thanks again.